# LED not turning off even after there are no unread WhatsApp messages

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, nexus-5

I have this random problem with WhatsApp: the green light that blinks when there are unread messages don't turn off even after I go and read them. It doesn't even help if I delete all the messages. The only thing that helps is restarting the phone.

I have a Nexus 5.

Comment: Are you using latest Whats.app version?

Comment: Yup. I am on the latest.

Comment: Is it possible to choose color? Can you try choosing white or some other color to test if that works?

Comment: The color doesn't change once this issue happens. Even turning off LED notifications from settings doesn't affect it. I even terminated the WhatsApp process; didnt help. Restarting the phone was the only way out.

Comment: Do you use stock ROM,GravityBox? This might not be caused by whats.app.

Comment: I am on stock ROM. I am not using any third party app to modify the LED. Although, I do have DashClock installed.

Comment: In whatsapp notification setting try  setting it to none and check if the problem persist then it may be due to some other problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what its worth, the issue stopped occurring after I changed the Whatsapp notification light color to white. I think it might have something to do with the fact that Whatsapp and Hangouts both had the notification light color set to green. If this happens to you try providing a distinct notification light color to all the apps.

Comment: This very same thing is happening to me on my LG G4 (which I just bought recently second hand).  It's rather annoying, definitely due to WhatsApp because whatever I change the colour to, that's colour which keeps flashing!  I'll try the white light, but tired changing a couple of times now and no luck.  Do you have any other advise?